# What is the use of sure-fire plugin in my pom

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, maven-plugin, maven-surefire-plugin

In my pom.xml there are two plugins added of surefire and I'm confused why are they used.

```
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.22.0</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <!--<skipTests>false</skipTests>-->
                            <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                            <!--  <forkMode>once</forkMode> -->
                            <!-- Sets the VM argument line used when unit tests are run. -->
                            <argLine>${surefireArgLine}</argLine>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*TestApp.java</include>
                                <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                                    
                    <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!--    <skipTests>false</skipTests>-->
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                    <!--  <forkMode>once</forkMode> -->

                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*TestApp.java</include>
                        <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                    </includes>
                    <argLine>-Xms128m</argLine>
                    <argLine>-Xmx512m</argLine>
                    <argLine>-XX:MaxPermSize=256m</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

also, if I just comment     true then my maven build starts to fail. can someone please explain this and also how to resolve this as well.
EDIT 1
Here is my error stack when I run maven test

```
**SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/D:/eclipse-jee-2022-09-R-win32-x86_64/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_3.8.601.20220820-1147/jars/maven-slf4j-provider-3.8.6.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [file:/D:/eclipse-jee-2022-09-R-win32-x86_64/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/917/0/.cp/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.MavenSimpleLoggerFactory]
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/D:/eclipse-jee-2022-09-R-win32-x86_64/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_3.8.601.20220820-1147/jars/maven-slf4j-provider-3.8.6.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [file:/D:/eclipse-jee-2022-09-R-win32-x86_64/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/917/0/.cp/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.MavenSimpleLoggerFactory]
[[INFO[m] Scanning for projects...
[[mWARNING[m] 
[[mWARNING[m] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.apc:designportal:war:22.1.2
[[mWARNING[m] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: junit:junit:jar -> duplicate declaration of version 4.12 @ line 430, column 15
[[mWARNING[m] Reporting configuration should be done in <reporting> section, not in maven-site-plugin <configuration> as reportPlugins parameter. @ line 973, column 20
[[mWARNING[m] 
[[mWARNING[m] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[[mWARNING[m] 
[[mWARNING[m] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[[mWARNING[m] 
[[INFO[m] 
[[INFO[m] [1m------------------------< [0;36mcom.apc:designportal[0;1m >------------------------[m
[[INFO[m] [1mBuilding SE Design Portal 22.1.2[m
[[INFO[m] [1m--------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------[m
[[mWARNING[m] The POM for com.apc.designtools:dp-quotingsystem-integration:jar:0.4 is missing, no dependency information available
[[mWARNING[m] The artifact org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:6.2.5.Final has been relocated to org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.2.5.Final
[[mWARNING[m] The artifact javax.xml:jaxrpc:jar:1.1 has been relocated to javax.xml:jaxrpc-api:jar:1.1
[[INFO[m] 
[[INFO[m] [1m--- [0;32mmaven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources[m [1m(default-resources)[m @ [36mdesignportal[0;1m ---[m
[[mWARNING[m] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[[INFO[m] Copying 14 resources
[[INFO[m] Copying 83 resources
[[INFO[m] 
[[INFO[m] [1m--- [0;32mmaven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile[m [1m(default-compile)[m @ [36mdesignportal[0;1m ---[m
[[INFO[m] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[[INFO[m] 
[[INFO[m] [1m--- [0;32mmaven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources[m [1m(default-testResources)[m @ [36mdesignportal[0;1m ---[m
[[mWARNING[m] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[[INFO[m] Copying 8 resources
[[INFO[m] 
[[INFO[m] [1m--- [0;32mmaven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:testCompile[m [1m(default-testCompile)[m @ [36mdesignportal[0;1m ---[m
[[INFO[m] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[[INFO[m] 
[[INFO[m] [1m--- [0;32mmaven-surefire-plugin:2.22.0:test[m [1m(default-test)[m @ [36mdesignportal[0;1m ---[m
[[INFO[m] 
[[INFO[m] -------------------------------------------------------
[[INFO[m]  T E S T S
[[INFO[m] -------------------------------------------------------
[[INFO[m] 
[[INFO[m] Results:
[[INFO[m] 
[[INFO[m] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[[INFO[m] 
[[INFO[m] [1m------------------------------------------------------------------------[m
[[INFO[m] [1;31mBUILD FAILURE[m
[[INFO[m] [1m------------------------------------------------------------------------[m
[[INFO[m] Total time:  3.939 s
[[INFO[m] Finished at: 2023-02-02T11:50:54+05:30
[[INFO[m] [1m------------------------------------------------------------------------[m
[[1;31mERROR[m] Failed to execute goal [32morg.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.0:test[m [1m(default-test)[m on project [36mdesignportal[m: [1;31mThere are test failures.[m
[[1;31mERROR[m] [1;31m[m
[[1;31mERROR[m] [1;31mPlease refer to C:\Users\SESA701739\Downloads\Repository for openJDK17\designportal\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.[m
[[1;31mERROR[m] [1;31mPlease refer to dump files (if any exist) [date]-jvmRun[N].dump, [date].dumpstream and [date]-jvmRun[N].dumpstream.[m
[[1;31mERROR[m] [1;31mThe forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?[m
[[1;31mERROR[m] [1;31mCommand was cmd.exe /X /C "D:\eclipse-jee-2022-09-R-win32-x86_64\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_17.0.4.v20220903-1038\jre\bin\java -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -jar C:\Users\SESA70~1\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire14215564203121122107\surefirebooter2253485858284748685.jar C:\Users\SESA701739\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire14215564203121122107 2023-02-02T11-50-54_343-jvmRun1 surefire12140783555302454556tmp surefire_04303044982407970188tmp"[m
[[1;31mERROR[m] [1;31mError occurred in starting fork, check output in log[m
[[1;31mERROR[m] [1;31mProcess Exit Code: 1[m
[[1;31mERROR[m] [1;31morg.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?[m
[[1;31mERROR[m] [1;31mCommand was cmd.exe /X /C "D:\eclipse-jee-2022-09-R-win32-x86_64\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_17.0.4.v20220903-1038\jre\bin\java -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -jar C:\Users\SESA70~1\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire14215564203121122107\surefirebooter2253485858284748685.jar C:\Users\SESA701739\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire14215564203121122107 2023-02-02T11-50-54_343-jvmRun1 surefire12140783555302454556tmp surefire_04303044982407970188tmp"[m
[[1;31mERROR[m] [1;31mError occurred in starting fork, check output in log[m
[[1;31mERROR[m] [1;31mProcess Exit Code: 1[m
[[1;31mERROR[m] [1;31m  at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:671)[m
[[1;31mERROR[m] [1;31m  at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:533)[m
[[1;31mERROR[m] [1;31m  at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:278)[m
[[1;31mERROR[m] [1;31m  at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:244)[m
[[1;31mERROR[m] [1;31m  at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1194)[m
[[1;31mERROR[m] [1;31m  at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1022)[m
[[1;31mERROR[m] [1;31m  at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:868)[m
[[1;31mERROR[m] [1;31m  at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)[m
[[1;31mERROR[m] [1;31m  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2(MojoExecutor.java:370)[m
[[1;31mERROR[m] [1;31m  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute(MojoExecutor.java:351)[m
[[1;31mERROR[m] [1;31m  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:215)[m
[[1;31mERROR[m] [1;31m  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:171)[m
[[1;31mERROR[m] [1;31m  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:163)[m
[[1;31mERROR[m] [1;31m  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)[m
[[1;31mERROR[m] [1;31m  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)[m
[[1;31mERROR[m] [1;31m  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)[m
[[1;31mERROR[m] [1;31m  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)[m
[[1;31mERROR[m] [1;31m  at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:294)[m
[[1;31mERROR[m] [1;31m  at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)[m
[[1;31mERROR[m] [1;31m  at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)[m
[[1;31mERROR[m] [1;31m  at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:960)[m
[[1;31mERROR[m] [1;31m  at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:293)[m
[[1;31mERROR[m] [1;31m  at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:196)[m
[[1;31mERROR[m] [1;31m  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)[m
[[1;31mERROR[m] [1;31m  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)[m
[[1;31mERROR[m] [1;31m  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)[m
[[1;31mERROR[m] [1;31m  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)[m
[[1;31mERROR[m] [1;31m  at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)[m
[[1;31mERROR[m] [1;31m  at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)[m
[[1;31mERROR[m] [1;31m  at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)[m
[[1;31mERROR[m] [1;31m  at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)[m
[[1;31mERROR[m] [1;31m[m
[[1;31mERROR[m] -> [1m[Help 1][m
[[1;31mERROR[m] 
[[1;31mERROR[m] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the [1m-e[m switch.
[[1;31mERROR[m] Re-run Maven using the [1m-X[m switch to enable full debug logging.
[[1;31mERROR[m] 
[[1

> Blockquote

;31mERROR[m] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[[1;31mERROR[m] [1m[Help 1][m http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException**
```

And for this I'm unable to get the idea. If I just comment the testfailureIgnore true so that would not be a solution.

Comment: Did you search the web first? Because it's part of standard Maven and has perfectly readable docs over on https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/

Comment: The first thing you should learn is to follow conventions (over configuration) which means naming the unit tests like `*Test.java` (details: https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#includes) also I would question why you need to setup such large memory configuration for unit tests... Furthermore I strongly recommend to use more recent versions of the plugins (general reference: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/) also this duplication in your pom file should produce warnings during the build.

Comment: If you have failures during your build it's really necessary to post those error outputs here because we have no magic glas bulb where we can see your logs...

Comment: @khmarbaise Please see the edit. Also, should I just remove the memory Configuration? because this is a heavy project so not sure on this part.

Comment: Check the failing tests and also the control sequences (color etc. are not helpful)... furthermore you have a lot of WARNING about deps. etc. Can you post your fuill pom file.... is that an OSGi project ?

Comment: @khmarbaise here is the link for my pom.xml - https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/2bizq00xp405scqh6olzd/Untitled.paper?dl=0&rlkey=eip2f62cu4utbpj063rt3wsxa and here is the proper log - https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/2bizq00xp405scqh6olzd/Untitled.paper?dl=0&rlkey=eip2f62cu4utbpj063rt3wsxa.

Comment: There are so manny warning and also no test being executed the apart from that the link to pom file is the same as to the log file ... make a github example project ....

Comment: @khmarbaise Can you please provide a resolution for this. Also my pom is https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/0mdpkej04lin0ikjds4a9/Untitled-1.paper?dl=0&rlkey=hu2zgfr5kp4ro4sq6jo04gr61